# How to raise an exception for a tensorflow out of memory error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, exception

I am running several tensorflow inferences using `sess.run()` in a loop and it happens that some inferences are too heavy for my GPU.

I get errors like :

```
2019-05-23 15:37:49.582272: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:623] 
Executor failed to create kernel. Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor of shape [306] and type float
```

I would like to be able to catch these specific OutOfMemory errors but not other errors (which may be due to a wrong input format or a corrupted graph.)

Obviously, a structure similar to :

```
try:
   sess.run(node_output, feed_dict={node_input : value_input})
except:
    do_outOfMemory_specific_stuff()
```

does not work since other kind of errors will lead to a call to the `do_outOfMemory_specific_stuff` function.

Any idea how to catch these OutOfMemory errors ?

Comment: It should be a [`tf.errors.ResourceExhaustedError`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/ResourceExhaustedError). This was suggested in the duplicate [How to catch tf.errors.ResourceExhaustedError in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52392502/1782792), but there was no further answer, can you try whether catching that works?

Comment: @jdehesa Yes it works, thank you. I think you can write that as an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to catch it via:

```
...
except tf.errors.ResourceExhaustedError as e:
    ...
```

according to [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/ResourceExhaustedError).

Comment: Could you show us how to proceed then when I catch the error? how can I flush the memory?

Comment: @Ghanem checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102727/8150685 or the answer above it. Either you can set it to grow or you will need to do it in batch sizes. Either way I don't know if you will use this exception unless you plan to implement a better ask forgiveness than permission type solution where you try to do it in one go but if it still runs out of memory than you batch it.